# Changes to XML file not reflected for different language

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to know why when I change the text between `<statement>` and `</statement>` to French, my app doesn't show anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<node>
    <id>1</id>
    <statement>Melbourne is the capital of Australia.</statement>
    <isCorrect>0</isCorrect>
    <desc>Canberra is the capital of Australia.</desc>
</node>
```

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: might be, that you get into troubles with special characters and *UTF-8*. This happens if you do not build the XML properly...

Comment: Can you show how you are reading in this file in Java?

Comment: Can you show the french version of that xml file?

Comment: @shmosel How i can turn it Off and On ?

Comment: @Zapl i just tried to translate this text to french (Melbourne is the capital of Australia.)

Comment: The point is: maybe your french text contains characters that would need to be escaped in XML or have other special meaning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Comment: @zapl ah i see. the sentence in french is : Melbourne est la capitale de l'Australie. 
so the problem could be this caracter ' .. right ?

Comment: It shouldn't but I would try it. `'`s are a common source of errors.